# Jquery: keydown() only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is that I click w and it will output an alert stating 'first Alert' then I want to be able to click w again and it will output 'second Alert'.

So what I have done here is I have created a variable called 'a' that I have set to 0 then I have 2 functions one called firstAlert and one called secondAlert which both add 1 to 'a'.

I have created an if statement to check if the user clicked w. Inside the if statement, I created a switch statement which checks the value of 'a' and runs a certain case depending on what value of 'a' is.

My problem here is that when I click w the first time, it will run the function firstAlert() and output "first Alert". But the second time I click w the second function doesn't run at all and on some browsers the first function keeps running when I click w.

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var a = 0;

    function firstAlert() {
      alert("first Alert");
      a + 1;
    }

    function secondAlert() {
      alert("second Alert");
      a + 1;
    }

    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
      if (key.which == 87) {
        switch (a) {
          case 0:
            firstAlert();
          break;

          case 1:
            secondAlert();
          break;

          default:
            a = 0;
          break;
      }
    }
  });
 });
```

Comment: `a + 1` => `a += 1`

Comment: `a + 1` => `a++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to increment a. 
Try **`a+=1;`**
(Equivalent to **`a=a+1;`**)

Comment: actually this does work it just doesn't work in my current browser

Answer (score 2):

Without correcting your other code, `a++` will give you what you're looking for:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var a = 0;

  function firstAlert() {
    alert("first Alert");
    a++;
  }

  function secondAlert() {
    alert("second Alert");
    a++;
  }

  $(document).keydown(function(key) {
    if (key.which == 87) {
      switch (a) {
        case 0:
          firstAlert();
          break;

        case 1:
          secondAlert();
          break;

        default:
          a = 0;
          break;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using modern jquery version (>3), this error happen sometime, and you should change the keydown event function to be like this:

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'document', function (){
     //Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var a = 0;

    function firstAlert() {
      alert("first Alert");
      a+=1;
    }

    function secondAlert() {
      alert("second Alert");
      a+=1;
    }

    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
      if (key.which == 87) {
        switch (a) {
          case 0:
            firstAlert();
          break;

          case 1:
            secondAlert();
          break;

          default:
            a = 0;
          break;
      }
    }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```